# Elasticsearch ignoring whitespaces and cases for facet terms

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

I have made my es schema with some fields marked as no_analysis for creating facets. But it seems some of my data contains whitespaces or lowercase letters. e.g.
for a field named color i have values "BLACK", "Black", "Black ", which leads to 3 different facet terms. Is there some way to handle this without making changes to data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can analyze your text without tokenizing it if you use the [keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html). That means that "Black Dog" would not be split into two tokens, but you can then apply token filters to modify the tokens, for instance lowercasing them using the [lowercase filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) and trimming them too using the [trim token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-trim-tokenfilter.html).

You need to create a [custom analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/custom-analyzer/) in your index settings and use it in your mapping for the field you're faceting on.

As a result you would index the only "black" token out of the three "BLACK", "Black" and "Black " provided as input.